# rails update with array of params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following params

```
post[:name]
post[:title]
post[:unique][:comment]
post[:unique][:date]
```

I tried update

```
test = post[:unique][:comment]
@post.update_attribute(:contest, test)
```

And getting error as

```
undefined local variable or method `post'
```

But normal update are working that is

```
@post.update_attribute(:name, :name) #This works
```

Comment: Please post the code in context.

Comment: actual problem is with this line "test = post[:unique][:comment]" ... hav u verified that post[:unique][:comment] is exist in params ???

Comment: What is `post`?? Are you confusing it for `params`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting `post[:unique][:comment]` in params then you just have to access it like

```
params[:post][:unique][:comment]
```

Comment: Ok I cannot check it now. Is it possible to convert all the values of the `params[:post][:unique]` to json?